# NodeJS - reading Parquet files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, parquet

Does anyone know a way of reading parquet files with NodeJS?

I tried `node-parquet` -> very hard (but possible) to install - it works most of the time but not working for reading numbers (numerical data types).

Also tried `parquetjs` but that one can read only parquet files created by it's own library. Anything created with Spark or Python - can not read.

Thanks

Comment: Parquet should be standard no ?

Comment: I had the same problem. After trying several packages I found **parquetjs-lite** from [https://github.com/ZJONSSON/parquetjs](https://github.com/ZJONSSON/parquetjs) which seems to be able to read all parquets I tried so far.

Comment: @B.Brink Thanks... parquetjs-lite worked for me

Answer (score 8):

> Does anyone know a way of reading parquet files with NodeJS?

I found many libraries but most of them are dead/not maintained.

- **parquetjs** - https://github.com/ironSource/parquetjs/issues/128
- **parquets** - https://github.com/kbajalc/parquets/issues/38
- **parquetjs-lite** - https://github.com/ZJONSSON/parquetjs
- **node-parquet** - https://github.com/skale-me/node-parquet/issues/62

> Also tried parquetjs but that one can read only parquet files created
> by it's own library. Anything created with Spark or Python - can not
> read.

I have not tried this library but parquet has a defined spec. We should be able to read a parquet file created from python or spark in JavaScript.

**Other option:**

- **DuckDB** - I would suggest to try this library. [DuckDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/duckdb) is an in-process embedded library/DB.

Below code snippet using **DuckDB** to read parquet data directly from disk.

```
var duckdb = require('duckdb');
var db = new duckdb.Database(':memory:');
db.all("SELECT * FROM READ_PARQUET('D:\\sample\\userdata1.parquet') WHERE Country='Canada' LIMIT 3", function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(res)
});
```

DuckDB has a lot of features built around parquet.

- Run SQL queries directly on parquet file on disk, read from S3, read from HTTP endpoint, we can even load very large parquet files into DuckDB format and run queries on the DB tables, join parquet data with other formats like CSV.
- Write parquet files onto disk, write parquet to s3 bucket.
- single file read, multi file read, read a folder/use glob expression.
- read schema and metadata, footer statistics.
- Parquet projection pushdown, filter pushdown.

Docs:

- [DuckDB node bindings](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/nodejs/overview)
- [DuckDB Parquet Docs](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/parquet)
- [Other DuckDB feature](https://duckdb.org/docs/)

Comment: any update about it ?

Answer (score 0):

[@dsnp-parquet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsnp/parquetjs) worked for me.  It is derived from parquetjs and parquetjs-lite and is alive at this time.